# How to drop the voltage from 3.8V to 3.3V - LDO or Schottky diode?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, schottky

What is the better way of dropping the voltage from 3.8V do 3.3V - using an LDO (e.g LP2985IM5-3.3) or the Schottky diode? It's about power supply for a microcontroller. 
I plan to use the ST1S10PHR step-down from 12V to 3.8V to power the GSM radio while I need 3.3V to power the MSP430 mcu. The input of the LDO or the Schottky would be the Vout of the ST1S10PHR step-down.

The problem I see with the Schottky diode is that the Vforward is a function of Iforward and this dependency is quite significant (e.g. for BAS70H: If=1mA -> Vf=410mV; If=15mA -> Vf=1V).

For the LDO LP2985IM5-3.3 I haven't found any particular limitation, however I met some chip that required the Vin to be Vout+1.5V. That is impossible in my case.

Comment: As you say a Schottky is a no-go, use a LDO.

Answer (score 4):

You have 500 mV headroom, so a LDO should be possible.  A diode is not a exact voltage drop.  The output of a LDO will be much better regulated.  Unless this is a very high volume product and the extra few cents actually matters, use a LDO.

Comment: 500mV is actually quite a lot. I don't expect the microcontroller to consume more than 100-150mA, and for that current, there is a large variety of LDOs available that have a guaranteed voltage drop below 500mV (and usually a typical value around 200-300mV). I have a small table of cheaper Microchip LDOs, so here's just a short list from my table: TC1071, TC1187, TC1173/4, MCP1725, MCP1755, MCP1801/2, MCP1824/5.

Comment: @tml: I wouldn't call something that requires 1.5 V headroom a "LDO".  "LDO" stands for low dropout.  1.5 V isn't really low dropout.  Lots of LDOs can work with 500 mV headroom, including the dirt cheap MCP1700.

Comment: Ok, so this is exactly what I was looking for: voltage drop, thanks! So the LP2985-N has 300 mV @ 150 mA load which makes it appropriate for my application.